# Facebook Graph API Return Friend posts only from feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I only get the posts of friends using Graph API?

Not the FQL I'm trying to make one long url call.

It may require using JPath in the /feed call?

Answer (score 2):

friend permissions are gone since v2.0 (end of April 2014), it is not possible to get the posts of friends anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog